# SOLR: Filtering by daterange

Tags: solr

I'm indexing many users (50 million+) and their pageviews per day, for example:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "foo bar"
  "views_2020_01_01": 1,
  "views_2020_01_02": 2,
  "views_2020_01_03": 3,
  "views_2020_01_04": 4,
  "otherfield": "xxx",
  "yetanotherfield": "yyy",
  "gimmeanotherfield": "zzz",
  "otherfields.......": "....."
  ....
},
{
  "id": 124,
  "name": "bar baz"
  "views_2020_01_01": 4,
  "views_2020_01_02": 3,
  "views_2020_01_03": 2,
  "views_2020_01_04": 1,
  "otherfield": "xxx",
  "yetanotherfield": "yyy",
  "gimmeanotherfield": "zzz",
  "otherfields.......": "....."
  ....
}
```

I store the view data of the last 2 years. Our webinterface makes it possible to select a daterange (for example `2019-06-01` to `2019-07-22`)

In this case, when we filter `show me users with more than 5 and less than 20 pageviews` in that daterange, i will make a query:

`{!frange l=5 u=11} sum(views_2019-06-01,views_2019-06-02,views_2019-06-03,...,views_2019-07-22)`

This is quite slow. I'm wondering if this is just bad practice or if anybody has a better way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Initial guess would be benchmark keeping a separate collection with `date: .., views: ..., name: ...`-documents, one document for each date with views. That way most lookups can be cached from disk and will interact directly with the built-in faceting/stats functions instead, and you can scale out the number of nodes over time. The number of documents in total could be an issue, since you'd at least need multiple shards (one shard can only keep 2^31 documents). Seeing as you're trying to find users, the query would need to look at all shards as well..

Comment: Another option would be to look at [the analytics support](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/analytics.html) as well as [streaming expressions](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/streaming-expressions.html) which are built to do this in parallel.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh but the documents not only contain the view-data but other data as well. I was thinking about solr joining two collections (another with id,date,views) and then joining both while filtering the dates and then filtering the sum of those?!

Comment: Sure, but you can have a separate collection with the view data. Joins (what's explicitly called joins in Solr) will only allow you to filter from another column, but that might work in this case. First I'd try to evaluate the performance at least, so you can find out if it's a viable solution for what you need.

Comment: @MatsLindh i just created another core `viewdata` with the same `user id` index. How would i write the query according to my needs?

Comment: Initial thought would be to create a sum facet on user_id, or use a direct sum(views) with {!frange} as in your example, with a `fq` set to limit the set of documents to those that you're interested in by date.

Comment: `direct sum(views) with {!frange} as in your example` - i try this, but it fails. i'm using `fq={!frange l=5 u=11}{!join from=id to=id fromIndex=views}sum(sales)` but it tells me `undefined field _text_` - What's wrong with that?

Comment: `_text_` is the default search field if nothing else is given. My guess is that the `{!frange}` expects the function to come directly after the closing tag, and that the join barfs it.

Comment: Have you considered creating aggregate fields by month or year? For example views_2020_01 for all January/2020 and views_2020 for all 2020

Comment: @HectorCorrea, yes but this still adds up and keeps the sorting/filtering slow.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 collections 1 is for users and 1 is for pageviews then use join query to get data. have a look on this article [Joining Collections in SOLR](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Joining-Collections-in-SOLR-Part-I/ta-p/246952).

Comment: Makes sense, could you make an example of the collections & queries for filtering / sorting?